# How to write a Integration test in Grails for Domain Class as a REST resource?

Tags: rest, grails, resources, integration-testing, grails-domain-class

I am using a Domain Class as a rest resource as mentioned in [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#domainResources)

So while using this approach there are no controllers or service classes created. And I tried to find a way to write Integration tests for the Domain as a REST resource but could not find it. So kindly tell me how to do it or post a link to somewhere which tells the same.

Regarding this approach, well it is the exact approach asked to make so I cannot change to other way of using REST services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Spock as your test framework:
https://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Example how to use it for REST:

```
class ExampleWebAppSpecification extends Specification {
    def "Should return 200 & a message with the input appended"() {

        setup:
             def primerEndpoint = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8080/' )
        when:
             def resp = primerEndpoint.get([ path: 'exampleendpoint', query : [ input : 'Get a hair cut' ]])
        then:
             with(resp) {
                 status == 200
                 contentType == "application/json"
             }
             with(resp.data) {
                 payload == "Something really important: Get a hair cut"
             }
    }
}
```

**EDIT -** 
In the buildConfig.groovy:

```
compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.0")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")

testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0")
testCompile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+")
testCompile("net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4+")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please tell the imports and plugins installed, if any? Because this RESTClient class is not available by default.

Comment: Add this to your buildConfig.groovy:  `compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.3"`

Comment: Yes actually I did that earlier after checking google. But there is one problem which is yet not resolved even after searching a lot is that when I add this in buildConfig and run the app to install it. Even then it shows me the error with red underline- `Groovy:unable to resolve class RESTClient`

Comment: Even few people suggested to use `import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder` and use RestBuilder but this also has the same error `Groovy:unable to resolve class`. I think these classes does not exist in the plugin anymore. Sorry but badly stuck in this code.

Comment: and then try to see if you can use this class

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping. I did that but without any success. I manually checked the `ProjectName\target\work\plugins\rest-client-builder-2.0.3` directory and found just 3 files - `application.properties`, `plugin.xml`, `RestClientBuilderGrailsPlugin.groovy`. But for every grails plugin there is directory called `grails-app`, that directory is not present here. Can that be the problem? No classes available there